# Proof Verification: Chapter 1 Exercise 6(a) of Baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

I have an idea for a proof, but I'm not sure it's valid, so I would like to hear your opinion.

**The Question**

Fix $b>1$.

(a) If $m, n, p, q$ are integers, $n > 0$, $q > 0$, and $r = \frac{m}{n} = \frac{p}{q}$, prove that

$$(b^m)^\frac{1}{n} = (b^p)^\frac{1}{q}$$

Hence it makes sense to define $b^r = (b^m)^\frac{1}{n}$.

**My Proof**

From Theorem 1.21 we know that there exists $y_1,y_2\in\mathbb{R}$, such that $y_1^n = b^m$ and $y_2^q = b^p$. We show $y_1=y_2$. $y_1^n = b^{rn}$ and $y_2^q = b^{rq}$. Hence $b^{rn} = (b\cdot b \cdot b \cdot ...)\cdot (b\cdot b \cdot b \cdot ...) \cdot (b\cdot b \cdot b \cdot ...) ...$ where the number of $b$'s in each $(b\cdot b \cdot b \cdot ...)$ is $r$ and the number of $(b\cdot b \cdot b \cdot ...)$ is $n$. Thus $b^{rn} = (b^r)^n$ and in the same way, we get $b^{rq} = (b^r)^q$. From the uniqueness of $y_1$ and $y_2$ it follows that $y_1 = b^r = y_2$.

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: I'm not sure if my argument holds when $m$ or $p$ are negative. Though maybe the problem is not concerned with negative powers since Rudin doesn't talk about them anywhere in this chapter.

Comment: ". where the number of b's in each (b⋅b⋅b⋅...) is r "  That simply makes no sense if $r$ is not an integer.

Comment: @fleablood You are right. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from "I'm not sure if my argument holds when m or p are negative."

It doesn't entirely.  Also you claim that it makes sense to define $b^r = (b*...*b)$ a number $r$ times.  That does not make *any* sense if $r$ is not an integer.

One subtle thing is Rudin introduces $b^n$ as shorthand for $b*.... *b$.  He doesn't bother to mention that $b^0$ and $b^{-n}; n\in \mathbb N$ are extensions of that shorthand.  He also doesn't state or think it's worth proving that $b^{n+m} = b^nb^m$.  However as, at this stage, as $b^n$ is just *shorthand* for $b*.... *b$ and writing numbers on paper is basic addition and addition is associative this doesn't actual require proof.  It's immediate.

I suppose if I were teaching this and I had all the time in the world to bore my students out of their skulls, and make comments as we introduce the field axioms I'd apply them to integers and exponents:

$b$ is in some field $F$ but the exponents $b^n$ or $b^m$ are so that $n,m$ are *integers* which are a subset of the field of rationals.

Multiplication in $F$ is a associative *and* addition in $\mathbb Z\subset Q$ is associative so: Therefore $b^nb^m = \underbrace{\underbrace{(b*b*...*b)}_{n times}\underbrace{(b*b*...*b)}_{m times}=(\underbrace{b*b*...*b}_{n times}\underbrace{b*b*...*b}_{m times})}_{\text{Associativity of Multiplication in F}}=$

$\underbrace{(\underbrace{b*b*...*b}_{n times}\underbrace{b*b*...*b}_{m times})=(\underbrace{b*b*....*b}_{n+mtimes})}_{\text{Associativity of addition in }\mathbb Z} = b^{n+m}$.

There exists a multiplicative identity $1$ in $F$ and additive indentity $0$ in $\mathbb Z\subset Q$.  Therefore $b^0*b^m = b^m$ and $b^0 = 1$.

There exist multiplicative inverses in $F$ and additive inverses in $\mathbb Z\subset Q$: Therefore $b^{-n}b^{n} = b^0 =1$ so $b^{-n}=\frac 1{b^n};$ the multiplicative inverse.

Distributive axiom in $\mathbb Z\subset \mathbb Q$; $m(n+p) = mn + mp$: Therefore $(b^m)^n=b^{mn}$ (because if $m = 1+1+1...+1$ then $m*n = n+n+....+n$).

According to Rudin all this can be taken as a given and is still just "shorthand".  But this changes with the idea of $b^r; r \in \mathbb Q$ which is not our shorthand.

Now as $(b^{\frac 1n})^n =  b^{\frac 1n*n} = b^1 = b$ it might make sense to claim $b^{\frac 1n} = \sqrt[n]{b}$ as $\mathbb Q$ is a field.  But in the field $F$ we have absolutely *no* reason to believe that such a number $y; y^n = b$ exists. (They certainly do not exist in the field $\mathbb Q$ as $\sqrt 2 \not \in \mathbb Q$ attests).  Nor if we thought such numbers existed we could we assume that if $\frac mn = \frac pq$ then the numbers $w,v$ so that $w^n = b^m$ and $v^q = b^p$ would in anyway imply that $w = v$.

Th. 1.21 proves that such positive numbers exist for positive members of the field $\mathbb R$ and that they are unique.

But Ex.  6a) is what we need to do show that such values would be consistent.

Now when we write $r = \frac mn = \frac pq$ we assume $m,n,p,q$ are integers but *also* $n>0;q>0$ (so if $r< 0$ then it is the integers $m$ and $p$ that are negative).

And $\frac mn =\frac pq \iff mq = np$.  Let $k = mq = np$

Let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be the unique numbers so that $y_1^n = b^m$ and $y_2^q = b^p$.  Then $y_1^k = y_1^{np}  =(b^m)^p= b^{mp}$ and $y_2^{k} = y_2^{mq} = (b^p)^m = b^{mp}$.  So $y_1^k = y_2^k = b^{mp}$ but by theorem $1.21$ such $y_1, y_2$ are unique so $y_1=y_2$.

---

Note:  the introduction and explanation as to *why* we are doing the exercise and what the exercise signifies was over 7 times as long as doing the exercise itself.

To mmy mind that was a singular oversight on Rudin's part.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I really appreciate it. I forgot to mention that $b$ is real since at the beginning of this problem set Rudin writes: "Unless the contrary is explicitly stated, all numbers that are mentioned in these exercises are understood to be real". There are a few things that I don't understand: 1. "...writing numbers on paper is basic addition..." - what do you mean by that exactly?

Comment: 2. $\underbrace{(\underbrace{b*b*...*b}_{n times}\underbrace{b*b*...*b}_{m times})=(\underbrace{b*b*....*b}_{n+mtimes})}_{\text{Associativity of addition in }\mathbb Z} = b^{n+m}$ - I don't understand how the associativity of addition is related, doesn't your previous line with the associativty of multiplication enough?

Comment: 3. "...$(b^m)^n=b^{mn}$ (because if $m=1+1+1...+1$ then $m∗n=n+n+....+n$)." - again I don't entirly understand that. In addition, doesn't this argument assume that $m$ is positive?

Comment: 4. "...$(b^{\frac 1n})^n =  b^{\frac 1n*n}$..." - how do you know that? Your proof that $(b^m)^n=b^{mn}$ was for $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: " I forgot to mention that b is real" That was clear in context.  The notation $b^n$ is defined that $b$ is a member of a group/ring/or field and $n$ is a non-negative integer.  My point is, when you take an analysis or abstract algebra class for the first time you are expected to forget everything you learned in elementary  school and reinvent/prove everything.  For me, it was a bit confusing that rudin expected us to prove $0*a=0$ and $1>0$ but we were allowed to take for granted everything about $b^n$. That was because $n$ is an integer, and integers still work the way we were taught.

Comment: ""...writing numbers on paper is basic addition..." - what do you mean by that exactly?"  I mean if you write down $b*b*b*....*b$ five times and then you write down $b*b*b*....*b$ six times the result is $b*b*...*b$ five plus six or eleven times. That's fundamental and doesn't need to be proven.  It's enough to state that multipliacation is closed and so that expression will have a value.  Although we do need to reinvent the laws of mathematics, we don't need to reinvent the addition property of exponents.  That is a basic rule of reality, not math.

Comment: " I don't understand how the associativity of addition is related," Hmm, you are right.  That isn't associativity of addition but the mere *definition* of addition.  But it is because of a fundamental concept of addition.  Just like adding 5 rocks to 6 rocks is always 11 rocks.

Comment: "again I don't entirly understand that. In addition, doesn't this argument assume that m is positive"  Yes it does.  But it doesn't matter.  $-|m| = (-1) + (-1)+.....$.  Rudin doesn't think this requires proving.  We can reinvent the wheel and prove it from scratch.  I was providing an alternative-- pointing out that everything we know about integer exponents follows immediately by the algebraic axioms of integers.

Comment: "how do you know that? "  We *don't* know that and I didn't claim that it was so.  I claimed that *if* $b^{\frac 1n}$ where to mean anything at all and if $(b^n)^m = b^{n*m}$ then $b^{\frac 1n}$ would have to mean some $y$ such that $y^n = b$.  But we don't know that such a $y$ must exist nor that it'd be unique if we did.  To prove *those* you need Th. 1.21 (that does tell you such unique $y$ does exist for positive values) and you need to do 6.a to show that that will be consistant in allowing us to define $b^r$ for rational $r$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Everything is clear now.

Comment: Is $n,m\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ when you prove $b^nb^m=b^{n+m}$

Comment: No... I assumed $n,m\in \mathbb N$ when I proved $b^nb^m = b^{n+m}$.  From there I *extended* the definition that $b^k;k\in \mathbb Z$ is to be defined *and follow the rules* we must have $b^0 =1$ (because $b^{m}=b^{0+m}=b^0\times b^m$ so $b^0 =\frac {b^m}{b^m} = 1$) and that $b^k; k< 0$ must be that $b^k = \frac 1{b^{|k|}}$ (because if $m=|k|;k=-m;m>0$ then $1=b^0=b^{-m+m} = b^{-m}b^m$ so $b^{k} = b^{-m} =\frac 1{b^m} = \frac 1{b^{|k|}}$.

Comment: The definition of $b^k = \underbrace{b\times b\times...\times b}_{k\text{ times}}$ only makes sense if $k \in \mathbb N$ and $k \ge 1$.  $b^0= \underbrace{b\times b\times...\times b}_{0\text{ times}}$ is not meaningful.  (Actually $b^1= \underbrace{b\times b\times...\times b}_{1\text{ times}}$ isn't meaningful either.)  But if we want to *extend* the definition to include $0$ (and $1$) *AND* we want to keep the rule $b^{n+m} =b^nb^m$ we *MUST* define $b^0 = 1$  (and $b^1 = b$).  ... This *hints* at the idea of $1$ being to multiplicative identity so multiply "zero" times is the identity.

Comment: ... and hints that multiplying a negative number of times is to take the inverse.... perhaps Rudin thought this was obvious and didn't ever bothering defining $b^n$ for $n \in Z; n\le 1$ nor thought the rule $b^{n+m}=b^nb^m;n,m\in \mathbb Z$ needed to be stated (much less proven).  (I don't think it's quite so obvious, or if it is, I don't think it is obvious *why* it is obvious.)

Comment: @fleablood Thanks for the reply. Correct me if i am wrong, to make things happen, we need to agree and extend the axiom $b^{n+m}=b^nb^m$ from naturals to integers. It seems that after I agree with this, $b^0=1,b^{-n}=\frac{1}{b^n},n\in\mathbb{N}$ come naturally. This is delicate since Rudin left it blank and I would like to understand where is the line drawn for axiom. By the way, if you would like to reply, please "@" my name such that the notification will ping me.

Comment: @AndesLam  *sigh*  .... you and me both... the way I see it.  Rudin very glibly said "for shorthand we will refer to $ab$ to mean $a*b$ and $a^k$ to mean $a*a*a*...*a$" and what he *didn't* explicitly point at was that $a,b$ were these *abstract* objects in a Field (it could be any field at this point but eventually we will concern ourselves with the Real Number Field) but the $k$ are *concrete* INTEGERS and Rudin assumes all properties of those fall naturally and need no explanation....

Comment: ... you (correctly) are concerned with defining a definition that was given for $N$ and want to extend it $\bb Z$.  Rudin doesn't think it needs exposition.  BUT WHAT *DOES* need exposition: Th 1.21 says that for any real $b > 0$ and any natural number $k$, there is a natural number $c$ so that $c^n = b$.  By pure *convenience* he called this $b^{\frac 1n}$ at this point there was *no* justification of it *looking* like a rational number.  He could have called it $\sqrt[k]b$. What need justifying is that .. . to be continued....

Comment: .... is that define $b^{\frac mn} = (\sqrt[n] b)^m$ is consistent.  That is that if $\frac cd = \frac mn$ then $(\sqrt[d] b)^c = (\sqrt[n]b)^m$ and the if $\frac mn=k\in \mathbb Z$ then $\sqrt[n](b)^m = b^k=b*b*b...b$. And that with the *new* and extended defintion that $b^{q+r} = b^qb^r$ is still a valid rule.  THAT is what Rudin thinks need to be validated.  .... And then we need to extend the definition to define $b^x; x\in \mathbb R$ and *that* is a whole other issue.

Comment: @fleablood First, sorry. when I was writing my first comment, I didn't read the entire comment thread since there were already much to digest from your reply. Second, after 2 hours of reading your reply and the entire comment thread back and forth, I dare to say I understand the motivation--that is $r=\frac{m}{n}\in\mathbb{Q},b^r=(b^\frac{1}{n})^m$ and the existence of said root. If I understand correctly, I would like to end this with my last doubt--how can you infer $b^{-n},n\in\mathbb{N}$ from existing field axioms, which seems to be what you did with $b^{n-n}=1$ or $b^{-n}=\frac{1}{b^n}$

Comment: The way I see it is that, I can't infer $b^0=1,b^{-n}=\frac{1}{b^n}$ from field axioms. However, I can define these notations and argue their existence due to field identity and multiplicative inverse. Now you have mentioned "This doesn't deserve exposition from rudin's pov. on the other hand, what does exposition...", does it mean that I should just leave these behind and focus on what's more important--the existence of root and its association with rational exponent?

Comment: Put it in this way. If Rudin find it trivial to infer from scratch, in what ways will I find $b^0=1,b^{\frac{1}{n}=b^{-n}},b^mb^n=b^{n+m}$ intuitive with existing field axioms?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128383/discussion-between-fleablood-and-andes-lam).